# Comparator (sort) to compare array list of objects with 3 properties by priority

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, jcr

So lets say there is a node, and it has three properties: `pdf:Title`, `dc:title` & `node name` , I would like to compare and sort the array based of these properties with priority in same order. So if node1 has all three properties and node2 has only `dc:title` it should compare `pdf:Title` of node1 with `dc:title`of node2.

This is the code I am using:

```
@Override
public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {


    try {
        int compareValue;
        boolean o1HasPdfTitle = o1.hasProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title");
        boolean o1HasDcTitle = o1.hasProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title");
        boolean o2HasPdfTitle = o2.hasProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title");
        boolean o2HasDcTitle = o2.hasProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title");

        if (o1HasPdfTitle && o2HasPdfTitle) {       
            compareValue = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title").getString().compareTo(o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title").getString());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (o1HasPdfTitle && o2HasDcTitle) {         
            compareValue = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title").getString().compareTo(o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title").getString());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (o1HasDcTitle && o2HasPdfTitle) {         
            compareValue = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title").getString().compareTo(o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title").getString());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (o1HasDcTitle && o2HasDcTitle) {          
            compareValue = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title").getString().compareTo(o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title").getString());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (!o1HasPdfTitle && !o1HasDcTitle && o2HasPdfTitle){
            compareValue = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title").getString());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (!o1HasPdfTitle && !o1HasDcTitle && o2HasDcTitle){
            compareValue = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title").getString());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (o1HasPdfTitle && !o2HasPdfTitle && !o2HasDcTitle){
            compareValue = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title").getString().compareTo(o2.getName());
            return compareValue;
        } else if (o1HasDcTitle && !o2HasPdfTitle && !o2HasDcTitle){
            compareValue = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title").getString().compareTo(o2.getName());
            return compareValue;
        } else {
            compareValue = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            return compareValue;
        }   

    } catch (Exception e) { 
            LOGGER.debug("CustomComparatorTitle debug message" + e);
            return 0;
    }
```

Problem: It does not sort correctly, they are not alphabetically ordered. Am I missing something?

Also is there a better way to wright the code without using so many conditions? I was trying to avoid the `IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure I understand your code, but it's seems its better in this way:

```
    final String pPdf="jcr:content/metadata/pdf:Title";
    final String pDC="jcr:content/metadata/dc:title";

    String[]  values=new String[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        Node curNode=i==0?o1:o2;

        if(curNode.hasProperty(pPdf))
            values[i]=curNode.getProperty(pPdf).getString();
        else if(curNode.hasProperty(pDC))
            values[i]=curNode.getProperty(pDC).getString();
        else
            values[i]=curNode.getName();
    }
    return values[0].compareTo(values[1]);
```

it's not better?